# Python byte instance issue

Tags: python, codec

Working on a personal Python project and Google's no help so here goes:
I'm trying to iterate through a python object and initially output it's contents via the web (Methods, attributes etc)

my code is here:

```
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
import codecs

def app(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    #yield b"<h1>Goodbye, World!</h1>"
    root=dir()
    for i in root:
      yield(b"<li>")
      yield(codecs.encode(i,"utf-8"),":info")
      for m in i:
        yield(b"<li>")
        #yield(codecs.encode(m,"utf-8"))
        yield(b"</li>")
      yield(b"</li>")
    yield(b"</ul>")
    return
 
server = make_server('127.0.0.1', 8080, app)
server.serve_forever()
```

Getting a "write() argument must be a bytes instance AssertionError: write() argument must be a bytes instance" however, I've tried everything that I and google can think of to resolve it and nothing works.

Any thoughts?

*Edit*

Stacktrace:

```js
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2020 15:17:43] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 266, in write
    "write() argument must be a bytes instance"
AssertionError: write() argument must be a bytes instance
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2020 15:17:43] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 65156)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 266, in write
    "write() argument must be a bytes instance"
AssertionError: write() argument must be a bytes instance

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 317, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 348, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 133, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2020 15:17:45] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 266, in write
    "write() argument must be a bytes instance"
AssertionError: write() argument must be a bytes instance
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2020 15:17:45] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 65399)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 266, in write
    "write() argument must be a bytes instance"
AssertionError: write() argument must be a bytes instance

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 317, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 348, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 133, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\Python3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: On which line is the error coming? Please post the trace.

Comment: Can you remove `return`? Because it is implicitly returning `None`.

Comment: @RonieMartinez without the return it will still implicitly return None.

Comment: @khelwood you are right.

Comment: Removed the return still getting the same error :|

Comment: What is that `":info"` supposed to do?  That line is yielding a tuple of two elements, which I suspect is the root cause of the problem.